Unable to connect Socket io in the nodejs server file with the frontend
This is my server.js file. I am unable to connect user in the websocket to server file. I have tried multiple approaches but none of them worked. I am using the same version of the socket-io file. My db connection is successful and server is listening as well but unable to connect socket io in the backend.
import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import connectDB from './databaseConnection/connectDatabase.js';
import userRoutes from "./routes/userRoutes.js";
import postRoutes from "./routes/postRoutes.js";
import messageRoutes from "./routes/messageRoutes.js";
import { v2 as cloudinary } from "cloudinary";
import { server, app } from './socket/socket.js';
dotenv.config();

connectDB();

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
});

// Middlewares
app.use(express.json({ limit: "50mb" }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Routes
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/posts", postRoutes);
app.use("/api/messages", messageRoutes);

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:3000`);
});

and this is socket.js file
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import http from "http";
import express from "express";
import Message from "../models/messageModel.js";
import Conversation from "../models/conversationModel.js";

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3001",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
});

export const getRecipientSocketId = (recipientId) => {
    return userSocketMap[recipientId];
};

const userSocketMap = {}; // userId: socketId


io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("User connected: ", socket.id);
    const userId = socket.handshake.query.userId;

    if (userId != "undefined") userSocketMap[userId] = socket.id;
    io.emit("getOnlineUsers", Object.keys(userSocketMap));

    socket.on("markMessagesAsSeen", async ({ conversationId, userId }) => {
        try {
            await Message.updateMany({ conversationId: conversationId, seen: false }, { $set: { seen: true } });
            await Conversation.updateOne({ _id: conversationId }, { $set: { "lastMessage.seen": true } });
            io.to(userSocketMap[userId]).emit("messagesSeen", { conversationId });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("user disconnected");
        delete userSocketMap[userId];
        io.emit("getOnlineUsers", Object.keys(userSocketMap));
    });
});

export { io, server, app };

I am unable to connect socket in the backend.
I have tried multiple things and this is my SocketContext.js file
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRecoilValue } from "recoil";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import userAtom from "../atoms/userAtom";

const SocketContext = createContext();

export const useSocket = () => {
    return useContext(SocketContext);
};

export const SocketContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
    const [onlineUsers, setOnlineUsers] = useState([]);
    const user = useRecoilValue(userAtom);

    useEffect(() => {
        const socket = io("/", {
            query: {
                userId: user?._id,
            },
        });

        setSocket(socket);

        socket.on("getOnlineUsers", (users) => {
            setOnlineUsers(users);
        });
        return () => socket && socket.close();
    }, [user?._id]);

    return <SocketContext.Provider value={{ socket, onlineUsers }}>{children}</SocketContext.Provider>;
};


Because you front-end is running in port 3001 and WS in 3000. Try this
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000', {
    query: {
        userId: user?._id
    }
});

More on How to use Socket.io with react
